# How can I make a conditional join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my tables structure:

```
// users
+------+----------+ 
|  id  |   name   |
+------+----------+
| 1    | Jack     |
| 2    | Peter    |
| 3    | Ali      |
| 4    | John     |
+------+----------+

posts
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id | author_id | editor_id |     title     |          content        |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | 4         | null      | title1        | content1                |
| 2  | 3         | null      | title2        | content2                |
| 3  | 1         | 3         | title3        | content3                |
| 4  | 3         | null      | title4        | content4                |
| 5  | 2         | null      | title5        | content5                |
| 6  | 2         | 1         | title6        | content6                |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

All I'm trying to do is getting names instead of ids in the `posts` table. So here is my query:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title, 
       p.content, 
       u1.name AS author_name, 
       u2.name AS editor_name
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON p.author_id = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON p.editor_id = u2.id
WHERE p.id = :post_id
```

Ok all fine. **What's my question?** As you see, in the most of times, `editor_id` contains `null`. So I don't need to have a join on it *(when its value is `null`)*. I mean second `LEFT JOIN` shouldn't occur in the most of times. So I want to implement an condition like this before second join:

```
IF ( p.editor_id <> null ) THEN 
   LEFT JOIN users u2 ON p.editor_id = u2.id
ENDIF
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your motivation for this?  What benefit do you perceive you'll get?

Comment: Its more complicated than that. If you remove the 2nd left join you have to loose the `u2.name AS editor_name` as you will no longer have a `u2` and the query will fail

Comment: @Ray My motivation is avoiding waste processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. And there's no need to do that.

The conditional test shown in the question  **`p.editor_id <> null`**  is guaranteed to evaluate to NULL, so it will never be TRUE. But even if we change that to a more reasonable  **`p.editor_id IS NOT NULL`**, there's still no point.

There's already an equality predicate that requires `u2.id` to be **equal to** `p.editor_id`.

That means that if `p.editor_id` is NULL, then it's impossible for the equality comparison to return TRUE.

It's not like the database engine is going to chunk through all of the rows in users to find a row that it already knows cannot exist.

So what is the point? I'm not understanding what you are attempting to achieve.

Are you attempting to affect the resultset that is returned (to get something different), or improve performance, or what?

---

It would be valid to change this:

```
 LEFT JOIN users u2 ON p.editor_id = u2.id
```

To this:

```
 LEFT JOIN users u2 ON p.editor_id = u2.id AND p.editor_id IS NOT NULL
```

But adding that condition doesn't change anything. It's redundant. The `p.editor_id = u2.id` is already checking that `p.editor_id` is not null; if it's null, then it's not possible for it to be equal to `u2.id`. (NULL is never "equal" to anything.)

Comment: Yes exactly I'm trying to improve performance ..! In other word, my motivation is avoiding waste processing.

Comment: @MartinAJ: If your goal is to improve performance, then take a look at the output of `EXPLAIN`. That will let you see the execution plan, the set of operations that MySQL will perform, and what indexes are used to satisfy the query. (And comparing EXPLAIN of the original query and a modified query will reveal whether those changes affect the execution plan. Oft times, creating appropriate indexes will allow MySQL to execute a more efficient set of operations. Running EXPLAIN after adding an index will reveal whether a new index will be used.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Not possible.

**Why:**

- The very nature of a `LEFT JOIN` is in itself a conditional.  It includes all records from the 'Left side' table and populate values that match from the right, otherwise supplies nulls when no match is found base on the join condition.
- A conditional functionality like you describe in SQL could create a broken query.  You can't just take an entire product of join out of a query, this is especially obvious if it's results are used elsewhere (like in the select parameters).

What you're attempting to do is unnecessary and would provide no added benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to specify the NOT NULL condition, that's the way LEFT JOIN would work (irrespective of whether you achieve your goal or not)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very few editor_id really present, I guess you can use correlated subquery in the select to get the editor's name.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title, 
       p.content, 
       u1.name AS author_name, 
       (select name from users u where u.id = p.editor_id) as editor_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON p.author_id = u1.id
WHERE p.id = :post_id
```